# Strange pixel column numbers in imported GeoTIFF file

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, import, dimensions

I am loading a .d file (from SAR ceos file) with 11,000 pixels x 11,000 columns into QGIS 3.16.4.

Perhaps this is a funny input format (not sure) but it appears that QGIS loads it well but reprojects it without my consent.

I would like to see the image in a rows and columns 11000x11000 visual (perhaps with lat long on cursor) but it appears that QGIS loads and reprojects it without my control (but with correct geographic position though) I see in the layer properties info that the file now has 13865 x 7052 pixels and geographic projection.

How do I keep the original spacing and then save it to e.g. a GeoTIFF with the same original 11,000 by 11,000 pixels?

My guess is that somehow the input format has the corner coordinates "switched", QGIS is able to fix that by reprojecting???  How do I work around this and export a fike in original dimensions as per above...

Comment: Where do you see that the image size 13865 x 7052?

Comment: QGIS does reproject geodata on-the-fly to the project's CRS but that is not altering the data itself. The layer's metadata always shows the actual, native dimensions. Is there any step before loading the data into QGIS or is it really the .d file that you are loadung in it?

Comment: I loaded the .d  file by dragging it into Qgis (no step before loading). Then I double clicked on the layer,  the information tab it showed 13865 x 7052 pixels.

Comment: I wish I could just convert the .d file to a geotiff using the original native dimensions. Please help, recommend..

Comment: And where did you get the information that the .d file has 11000x10000 pixels? What does gdalinfo report about the original? Can you share the image?

Comment: If you don't want the layer to be reprojected, just set the project CRS to be the same of the layer CRS. Alternatively, you can disable all the projection handling (automatic on "the fly” CRS transformation / reprojection included) just setting the "No CRS" option.
 Please read the QGIS Desktop User Guide / Manual https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#project-coordinate-reference-systems

Comment: Moreover, you are using an outdated and no longer supported QGIS version which very likely uses an outdated and no longer supported GDAL library version to read such raster layer.

Comment: ** begin of Map Projection Data record **

Map Projection Descriptor = GEOCODED                        
Number of Pixels = 11000
Number of Lines  = 11000
Nominal inter-pixel distance in output (m) =  50.000000
Nominal inter-line distance in output (m) = 50.000000
Orientation at center = 0.000000
Actual platform orbital inclination (deg) = 98.580231
Actual ascending node (deg) = 272.084015
Platform distance from center to geocenter = 7163681.500000
Altitude of platform rel. to ellipsoid (m) = 800649.812500
Actual groundspeed at nadir = 6625.352539

Comment: Thank you for the comments and questions: 1. I updated QGIS (some improvement but no change to my issues). 2. I added above a portion of the descriptor record .L associated with the .D data file. It is orientated along the flight direction and is 11,000x11,000 (I have seen it in an independent viewer correctly). Is there a way of not just loading but also saving as geotiff in native spacing. I can not do it even with the good comments and suggestions above.... Thank you for any additional help/comments!

Comment: The source code of the driver is here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/ceos2/sar_ceosdataset.cpp. Maybe the comments say something to you?

Comment: Thank you. Based on my basic investigations it seems dat the qgis reader is succesfully converting the original files in native flight direction spacing to a projected file in different spacing (latlon). It seems not possible to extract/export the original file. I hope I am wrong...   I could provide the input file (what is the best way for this forum?). Source code mentioned by user30184 was possibly used by qgis developers for reading the input data. I still hope an expert here might further explain the qgis reader functionality and possibly a way to extract geotiff imagery in native pixels.